# Condition Error: Property is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I've have a workflow whose root activity is a custom NativeActivity with a public InArgument called XmlData. When I try and use this argument in a child If activity I get the following error using XmlData within the condition:

```
'XmlData' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level
```

My properties look like this:

```
public Activity Body {get;set;}
public InArgument<CustomObj> XmlData {get;set;}
```

and this is the CacheMetadata method:

```
protected override void CacheMetadata(NativeActivityMetadata metadata)
    {
        var runtime = new RuntimeArgument("XmlData",typeof(CustomObj),ArgumentDirection.In,true);
        metadata.Bind(this.XmlData,runtime);
        metadata.AddArgument(runtime);

        metadata.AddChild(Body);
    }
```

I'm adding the argument inside CacheMetadata using the metadata.AddArgument method, and I've tried adding the child property it has using both AddChild and AddImplementationChild.

If I replace my custom activity with an ActivityBuilder and use code to create a DynamicActivityProperty then the condition can be compiled successfully, so I don't see what I'm missing when I use my own code.

Comment: Sharing some code would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry for not adding them to start with. They're now added.

Comment: What happens if you comment out the CacheMetadata function? The default implementation should be good enough. Also is the CustomObj a public type? The error  suggest is is internal.

Comment: Same issue if I rely on reflection too. It's a public type on a public property. ActivityBuilder creates arguments as an internal property, which would explain why it works when I use that.

Comment: Someitems you get weird errors like this when type names match namespace names or the full namespace contains the same name multiple times.

Comment: Are you using the activity in a workflow defined in code or in XAML? Is it a runtime error, from when the workflow runs CacheMetadata?

Comment: This is a pure XAML workflow, and yes - it is a runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 possible solutions I can think of, one is daft, one is hacky and the other vaguely sensible.

Solution 1 (the daft one)
Promote the RuntimeArgument to a private readonly member and swap the Bind and AddArgument calls around, I've had a few random occurances where this has helped.

Solution 2 (the very hacky one)
You can always put the values in a named property on the context and pull it out in the child

Solution 3 (the sensible one)
If you want to pass the InArgument to a child, bind it to a variable and bind the child to the variable.

Any of those help?
John